# FTP Connection is not open

Tags: java, android, ftp

Здравствуйте. Использую в своем приложении библиотеку Commons Net 3.4 от Apache и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. При попытке подключиться к FTP серверу выдает ошибку: "java.io.IOException: Connection is not open". Может кто-нибудь помочь с данной проблемой? Данные от FTP введены 100% правильно.

```
public static Boolean downloadAndSaveFile(String server, int portNumber, String user, String password, String filename, File localFile) throws IOException {
    FTPClient ftp = null;

    try {
        ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.connect(server, portNumber);

        ftp.login(user, password);
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));
            success = ftp.retrieveFile(filename, outputStream);
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }

        return success;
    } finally {
        if (ftp != null) {
            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: пермишн в манифесте присутствуют? делаем сие в бэкграунде?

Comment: @ermak0ff прописан android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: иии? результат каков?

Comment: @ermak0ff результат таков, что через FTP менеджер подключается, а через приложение - нет

Comment: ошибка какая теперь?

Comment: @ermak0ff я прописал permission еще до того, как выложил сюда пост. Поэтому ошибка осталась прежней.

Comment: ок, первое отпадает, что насчет второго вопроса?

Comment: @ermak0ff все выполняется в основном потоке

Comment: ну так и вынесите это выполнение в бэкграунд

Comment: @ermak0ff спасибо огромное за подсказку. Проблема решилась при помощи AsyncTask. Извиняюсь, что не ответил раньше. Можете написать ниже ответ, чтобы я пометил его как верный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причиной данной ошибки может служить:

- отсутствие соответствующего разрешения в манифесте;
- выполнение метода в `UI`-потоке.

Соответственно решается:

- добавлением `android.permission.INTERNET`;
- запуском метода в `бэкграунде`.